# Comprised of both

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What is the answer I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> decagon rainbow

Not only does this describe the picture, but

> if you label the points on the decagon 0-9 (starting from the top, going clockwise), then for each decagon write down the numbers the line starts/ends at, you get `04 05 03 01 07 15 14 18 01 09 14 02 15 23` - Convert with A1Z26, and you get the string `decagon rainbow`

Comment: Very fast! That's the answer. Well done.